# Migrated from selenium RC to Web Driver. Alternative for mouseDown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

What is the method used for mouseDown() in Selenium Web Driver?
public void mouseDown(String locator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example:

```
    driver.get("http://www.sbsddsd.com/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Actions act = new Actions(driver);

WebElement parentMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='abc')]"));

act.contextClick(parentMenu).build().perform();

        act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();

        act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();

        act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

All advanced interaction in Webdriver are handled through Actions class. I am giving you an example below:

```
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(WebElement).click();
builder.perform();
```